# Jquery UI: Combining blind and fade effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I want to combine blind and fade.

Fade works by changing the opacity of an element, and blind I think, by changing the width/height.

My goal is to create an animation where the edge of the element would fade away across the screen, aka a combination of blind and fade. I don't know if there's a term for it.

But anyhow, is this possible to do and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm thinking of right now is to break the fading element into 1px pieces and then fade each pixel individually at the same time as the blinding is occurring. I cannot imagine this being smooth with current browsers.

I'm just going to tentatively call this 'not possible'.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#box").animate({height:'0',opacity:'0'}, { complete: function() {this.remove()} });
```

Just use animate?

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked some time ago, but these days this can be done with jquery/jqueryui like so:

```
$('#test').hide("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1500)
    .fadeOut(1500)
    .dequeue();
```

You can use multiple functions at the same time by calling `.dequeue()` repeatedly as well:

```
$('#test').hide("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1500)
    .hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1500)
    .fadeOut(1500)
    .dequeue()
    .dequeue();
```

The above will use the slide and blind effect on hiding "test" while fading  at the same time. Here's a jsfiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/DirectCtrl/rVp35/1/

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the [jQuery animate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) function. This basically allows you to linearly interpolate between CSS values (From whatever the object starts with to values you define) over a set amount of time. So you could use this to alter opacity and width on your own to achieve the effect you want.

Be careful doing this though, as you'll need to account for all the variants of opacity, since IE doesn't yet support the standard "opacity: value;" one.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the usefulness of the animate method. However I'm not seeing a way of syncing the opacity and width change so that the opacity only changes where the width is changing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is by using jQuery UI and either the [toggleClass](http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) or [addClass](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/) functions. What these functions do is animate from one class to another so essentially you just define a start state and a end state and the functions take care of the rest.

Hope this helps out!

click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/physcosmurf/ByLMC/2/) for the fiddle

**CSS**

---

```
.divHidden{
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 0.0;
    width: 0px; /*Set to 0 so div is not visible */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}

.divShown{
    opacity: 1.0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

---

```
<button>Click me</button>
<div id="test" class="divHidden">Testing</div>
```

**Javascript**

---

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#test').addClass('divShown', 2000);
});
```